# VMware deadlock

Tags: vmware-player

I had to temporarily downgrade my computer and I can't get a *suspended* wmware VM running.

- The VM can't be started as there are fewer processors than required in the settings.
- The settings can't be changed since the VM is not shut down.
- The VM can't be shut down, 'cause it can't be started.

Is there a way around it?

<sup>In case it matters, I'm running vmware player 4.0.2 build-591240 on Ubuntu 11.10.</sup>

<sup>Moving the VM temporarily to a better computer is not an option (the overhead is too high and I'm expecting new hardware soon).</sup>

Comment: Could it start again once the number of processors has been corrected?

Comment: I hope so.... at least this is the thing it complains about now. IIRC, I could change such settings at will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete the `<machine>.vmss` file located in your virtual machine's storage directory and it will be as if you cut power and should be able to start/alter settings.

Comment: Data loss will occur if files/databases were not saved before suspending.  But this should get you up and running.